# Stripping Html content from response

Tags: java, html, spring-security

We need to remove particular string from HTML response created by server through JAVA code. For example, I need to remove comment tag  from the HTML response before sending the response to client. Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: <!-- ZK 5.0.6 2011022418 -->
This tag I want to remove from HTML content in response

Comment: can you show the code you're using and the output you're currently having?

Comment: Is this comment tag fixed or can be changed on runtime?

Comment: If it is fixed, you can first write response not to `response.getWriter()`, but to `StringBuilder` object, then remove your tag substring from it using `indexOf()` and `delete()`, then write resulting object to `response.getWrtiter()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int lowerIndex = <response String>.indexOf('<!--'));
int upperIndex = <response String>.indexOf('-->'));
```

You will get starting and ending indexes of the comment tag.
Then you can do

```
String newString = <responseString>.substring(0,lowerIndex)+<responseString>.substring(upperIndex)
```